# Run-time error "Method 'Open' of object '_Connection' failed" when I save the Excel file to a different location/ rename the file

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sharepoint

I am using the code below to connect through SQL.

When I try to save the file to a different location or rename the file then I get the error message.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim sPath As String
Dim sconnect As String
Dim rng As String
Public cn As New ADODB.Connection

Public Sub db_conn()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    'rng = Sheet2.Range("sales_data").Address
    
    If cn.state = adStateOpen Then cn.Close
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Readonly=True"""
        .Open
    End With
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

> Method 'Open' of object '_Connection' failed

[image]

This Excel workbook will be placed in the company's SharePoint site and from there users download the file into their local drives.
Everyone is getting this error message for the first time.
If they close the file and re-open from their local drives, then it is working.

When I do the **Save As**, it shows a SharePoint location path like below and because of that it is showing that run-time error message.

`https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxx_companyname_com/Documents/Desktop`

After closing and re-opening the file it will show the desktop location path like below though the file is in the same location.

`C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive - Companyname\Desktop`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I implemented this workaround:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection

Dim localName As String
Dim path() As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
   
   Set con = New ADODB.Connection
   con.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   con.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
   
   Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FullName
   
   If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.FullName, "https://") = 1 Then
      path = Split(fso.GetParentFolderName(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "/")
      localName = Environ("OneDrive")
      ' Or localName = Environ("OneDriveCommercial")
      For i = 6 To UBound(path)
         localName = fso.BuildPath(localName, path(i))
      Next i
      localName = fso.BuildPath(localName, ThisWorkbook.Name)
      con.Properties("Data Source") = localName
   Else
      con.Properties("Data Source") = ThisWorkbook.FullName
   End If
    
   Debug.Print con.Properties("Data Source")
   con.Open
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me!

As written here, the code could be simplified a bit by removing the fso.GetParentFolderName() call inside the Split function. Then the subsequent line that calls fso.BuildPath to join localName and ThisWorkbook.Name is unnecessary. Since we need the workbook name in the end anyway, there's no need to strip it from ThisWorkbook.FullName.